# How to record and replay sound in browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to write a web version of Talking Tom, which would record what you say and play them again.
But I can't find api for record sound in browser.... is it possible?
I'd like to write a Chrome App, so no need to worry about other browsers.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: For those of us not familiar with Talking Tom can you please explain what you'll be doing with the recorded sound or is it just replayed? If not HTML5's [speech input](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#speech-input) might be useful to capture at least what was said.

Comment: @Alasdair: Talking Tom records what you say and the plays an altered and (supposedly) funny version back to you after you stop talking.

Answer (score 1):

FLASH has support for microphone - its about your only option as far as I know.

Comment: As far as I know, Flash is the only way to do this.